# C - http post request with libcurl

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, post, curl

I'm using the code at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html to try a make a post request to a web service that I frequently and successfully use, but with nodejs/javascript.  I can get the post request to work from javascript but not from C with libcurl.

My C code is pretty much the code at the above link,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  /* get a curl handle */
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
       /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the data. */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://webservice.i.use.com/this/that");
       /* Now specify the POST data */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "token=TOKEN&product=PROD&timeinterval=ONE_MINUTE&datetime=2013-10-22+19:10")
       /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
       /* Check for errors */
  if(res != CURLE_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));

      /* always cleanup */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
return 0;
}
```

With a return of,

```
<Cdata>
  <Data />
  <Success>false</Success>
  <Message>Authentication Failed</Message>
</Cdata>
```

The same basic information (URL and POST data), using the nodejs needle package, returns the successfully authenticated result. The Javascript code is,

```
var needle = require('needle')
needle.post('http://webservice.i.use.com/this/that',
    {token:'TOKEN' , product:'PROD' , timeinterval:'ONE_MINUTE' , datetime:'2013-10-22+19:10'},·
    function(err, resp, body){
       console.log(body);
    });
```

Is there some extra information that the nodejs `needle` package is sending, that isn't being sent with the above C code?

I also tried with the `curl` CLT

```
curl -data "token=...." "url ...."
```

but this also did not work.

And recently adapted the code at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html to end up with the same authentication error message as above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved, the token value had a '+' in it, which need to be %2B.